# How to write an argmax function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm not talking about `tf.argmax` but about argmax in the mathematical sense, e.g. given a discrete set of values and a function find the value that maximizes it. I currently have something like this

```
input = tf.placeholder(name='input')
Qhat = do_stuff_to(input) # e.g. tf.add(input, 3)
```

Now I want to define another TensorFlow node, `max_Qhat`, which will take an array of Tensors as its argument. It will feed each of these tensors to `Qhat` and return the one that resulted in the greatest value. How do I do this? (**NOTE** I am not looking to *run* Qhat, so no `session.run`. I just want to *define* a function that evaluates it.)

Code I have so far:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(name='inputs')
max_Qhat = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an input tensor, say of dimensions `[k, ...]` (this is your "array" of `k` input tensors that we "maximize" over) then compute the Qhat op over the first axis/dimension of the input tensor (eg. using `tf.map_fn`) such that it returns a tensor of function values of dimensions `[k]` and then determine the maximum of this returned tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf;

sess = tf.InteractiveSession();

# define inputs
inputs = tf.constant([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [4, 3, 6, 2, 1],
    [9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
    [0, 1, 3, 5, 2]
], shape = (4, 5));

# the function/op that we want to compute for each input tensor
def some_op(t):
    return tf.reduce_sum(t);

# compute the function values
q = tf.map_fn(some_op, inputs);

# determine the index of the input tensor that maximizes the function
index = sess.run(tf.argmax(q, axis = 0));
maximizer = sess.run(inputs[index]);
```